# Left GL(k)-invariant metric on noncompact Stiefel manifold S(k,n)

Tags: riemannian-geometry

For $0<k<n$, the (noncompact) Stiefel manifold $S(k,n)$ is defined by all k-frames in an n-dimensional Euclidean space, or equivalently, all $k\times n$ real full-rank matrices. This is a principal $GL(k)$-bundle over $G(k,n)$, the Grassmannian. There is a $GL(k)$ action on the left.

My question is that, is there a left-invariant Riemannian metric on $S(k,n)$？

Thanks in advance!